# didBeginContact isn't being called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

so I've been working on this game for a while all works the way I want it, however I have been stuck on the didBeginContact for a couple of days now and I can't wrap my head around it, I think it looks okay and I've checked a few forums and got it almost identical so it would work for my game. But still nothing :( any help will be greatly appreciated. 
So this is my didBeginContact:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("i worked")
    // Every contact has two bodies, we do not know which body is which.
    // We will find which body is the penguin, then use the other body
    // to determine what type of contact is happening.
    let otherBody:SKPhysicsBody
    // Combine the two penguin physics categories into one mask
    // using the bitwise OR operator |
    let bunnyMask = PhysicsCategory.bunny.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.bunnyDamaged.rawValue
    // Use the bitwise AND operator & to find the penguin.
    // This returns a positive number if bodyA’s category is
    // the same as either the penguin or damagedPenguin:
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & bunnyMask) > 0 {
        // bodyA is the penguin, we want to find out what bodyB is:
        otherBody = contact.bodyB
    }
    else {
        // bodyB is the penguin, we will test against bodyA:
        otherBody = contact.bodyA
    }
    // Find the contact type:
    switch otherBody.categoryBitMask {
    case PhysicsCategory.grass.rawValue:
        print("nom nom grass")
    case PhysicsCategory.mud.rawValue:
        print("mud hit")
    case PhysicsCategory.stone.rawValue:
        print("ow my head")
    case PhysicsCategory.lava.rawValue:
        print("it burns")
    case PhysicsCategory.hedgehog.rawValue:
        print("stop touching me!")
    default:
        print("Contact with no game logic")
    }
}
```

This the bunny's code:

```
class Bunny : SKSpriteNode, GameSprite{
var currentSpeed: Double = 5

var textureAtlas: SKTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "bunny.atlas")
var moveAnimation = SKAction()
func spawn(parentNode: SKNode, position: CGPoint, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)) {
    parentNode.addChild(self)
    createAnimations()
    self.size = size
    self.position = position
    self.runAction(moveAnimation, withKey: "moveAnimation")
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size)
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.bunny.rawValue
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.hedgehog.rawValue
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.hedgehog.rawValue
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

}
```

And the bunny's GameScene code:

```
initialBunnyPosition = CGPoint(x: 25, y: self.size.height)
    bunny.zPosition = 1000
    bunny.spawn(world, position: initialBunnyPosition)
```

Anyone who has anything please help, if you need more code snips please let me know and I will supply with more info. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set the delegate for contacts ? (self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self)

Comment: Yes I have and still nothing :(

Comment: Have you create a correct physic boundaries for all your characters :) ?

Comment: I have used `self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size)` for each of of my nodes is that what you mean? Sorry if I sound stupid I'm very new to SpriteKit and game development.

Comment: Is "i worked" getting printed? Can you tell us your PhysicsCategory raw values? Does your Gamescene class implement the SKPhysicsContactDelete protocol?

Comment: No "I worked" is not getting printed, my PhysicsCatergory raw vals are `enum PhysicsCategory:UInt32 {
    case bunny = 1
    case bunnyDamaged = 2
    case grass = 4
    case mud = 8
    case stone = 16
    case lava = 32
    case hedgehog = 64
}` 
Yes I have implemented the SKPhysicsContactDelegate to the GameScene.

Answer (score 0):

When you set your physicsBodies to your project, you could define also the boundaries where your characters will be playing and collide.

First of all you must insert `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` to use `didBeginContact` method and set the delegate as below..

This is only an example where you can start :

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate { 
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -6) //gravity
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self  //

        // Set physics boundaries
        let fieldBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        self.physicsBody = fieldBody
        self.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        self.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        self.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
        self.physicsBody!.mass = 0.8
        self.physicsBody!.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0
        self.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0
        self.physicsBody!.restitution = 0
        self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.field.rawValue
        self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.hedgehog.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.bunny.rawValue
        //self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a boundary for collisions to work, only to stop characters going off the edge of the screen, but this could be accomplished in other ways. If the OP's sprites are touching/overlapping without dBC being called, then boundaries are not his problem.

Comment: In fact there are not only boundaries in my example Steve, I've reported also how to define class, how to set delegate, obviusly I cannot know if OP have setted all physicsBodies correctly but as I've explained this is only a point where OP can start (due to few informations in question)

Comment: It kinda worked, now I'm getting "I worked" & "Contact with no game logic" but thanks very much for your help. :)

Comment: Conor - see the new answer I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Conor - you say your dBC is now being called. Have you got this working yet? If not, try this for your `didBeginContact`, just to see if it identifies the right collisions:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    print("i worked")
      let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

       switch contactMask

       case PhysicsCategory.bunny.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.grass.rawValue:
        print("nom nom grass")
    case PhysicsCategory.bunny.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.mud.rawValue:
        print("mud hit")
    case PhysicsCategory.bunny.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.stone.rawValue:
        print("ow my head")
    case PhysicsCategory.bunny.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.lava.rawValue:
        print("it burns")
    case PhysicsCategory.bunny.rawValue | PhysicsCategory.hedgehog.rawValue:
        print("stop touching me!")
    default:
        print("Contact with no game logic")
    }
}
```

It doesn't do anything for `PhysicsCategory.bunnyDamaged.rawValue`, but we can add that in if we can get the basic detection working.

Comment: Man, the OP has request why didBeginContact isn't being called and you post a didBeginContact example? What kind of help can give this post?

Comment: @Allessandro - the OP has stated in comments that his didBeginContact is now being called, but none of this contact tests are matching, so I though I'd post a dBC layout that works for most people, to see if that helps him.

Comment: I don't know you so I am not interested in making sarcastic with you, I'm speaking about the thread title and your post, usually when OP speaking about other question the right way is to say: please you must open another question about this new issue that does not concern your request or edit the question you're answering to improve the clarity and focus answer , people dont have time to read all comments http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I will try now, I'll post later on the result. Thanks for your input

Comment: Hey Steve, I have tried this still no luck :( it's strange as every node has got its Bitmask number allocated just fine, but the contact just isn't working.